# alternate between two combination clauses in regex

Tags: regex, clojure

Given the following 2 strings -

```
select * from abc;
select * from abc where;
```

I want the regex to match anything -

1. after `from` till `;`.
2. between `from` and `where`.

The following 2 regex works for the above 2 cases -

```
(re-find #"(?<=from |FROM ).*(?= where| WHERE)" "select * from abc where")   => abc
(re-find #"(?<=from |FROM ).*(?=;)" "Select * from abc;")                    => abc
```

How do I combine the above 2 regex to work for both the above strings?

I tried the following but this doesnt work -

```
(re-find #"(?<=from |FROM ).*(?= where| WHERE)|(?=;) " "select * from abc;") => nil
```

**EDIT -**

How do I also make the regex work for the following strings -

```
select * from abc \n where;
select * from abc   \n \n;
```

The statement is always terminated using `;`.

However there could be blank spaces or newline characters before it.

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your regex as follows. The `(?i)` modifier is for case-insensitive matching:

```
user> (re-find #"(?i)(?<=from ).*?(?= where|;)" "SELECT * FROM abc WHERE")
"abc"
user> (re-find #"(?i)(?<=from ).*?(?= where|;)" "Select * from abc;")
"abc"
```

**Update:** You can include the `s` modifier to force the `.` to span across newlines.

```
(re-find #"(?si)(?<=from ).*?(?= where|;)" "select * from abc \n where;")
```

Comment: What about "WHERE" (in caps)?

Comment: The `(?i)` modifier takes care of that.

Comment: Also in the match statement '.*?', what is the role of '?'. I see without it the regex doesnt work. (I know the role of ? in general is to select 0 or 1 elements of the preceeding pattern).

Comment: The s modifier works, however it selects the \n also, how do I exclude it ?

Comment: @murtaza52, you can use `(?si)(?<=from ).*?(?=\s*where|\s*;)`

Answer (score 2):

Just include the `;` inside the lookahead.

```
"(?<=from |FROM )[\s\S]*?(?= where| WHERE|;)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fI0hV3/1)

Comment: Doesnt '.' work for all characters ? Why do I need to specify space and new line characters using \s ?

Comment: dot matches all the chars except for line break(newline char or `\r`) unless you don't specify the DOTALL modifier (?s)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=from )([\s\S]*?)(?= where|;)
```

Use this if you want to capture multiline statements as well.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/26

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s
'select * from abc;'
>>> s2
'select * from abc where;'
>>> s3
'select * from abc WHERE;'
>>> s4
'select * from abc \n where;'
>>> s5
'select * from abc   \n \n;'
>>> s6
'select * from efg   \n \n;'
>>> s7
'select * from efg  where \n \n;'
>>> for i in s, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7:
...     re.search(r'from (\S+)(?:\s+)?(?=;|where)', i, flags=re.I).groups()
...
('abc',)
('abc',)
('abc',)
('abc',)
('abc',)
('efg',)
('efg',)
>>>
```